how to handle if a goroutines call another goroutines in golang
Below, I have pasted pseudo-code.
I am new to Golang and would like to understand how to use goroutines.
I want to ensure that my program does not crash due to deadlocks. How can I effectively wait and call goroutines, especially in situations where one goroutine calls another?
if a goroutine G1 call another goroutine G2 who will be responsible for handling G2, is it G1 or the main process?
How we want to call goroutines
package main
import "fmt"

func rule2(){
    ruleList2 = int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    for _, val := range ruleList2 {
        go func() {
          //do somethings  
        }()
    }
    return result
}

func ruleCalled(key int){
    if key == 2 {
        return rule2()
    }
    
    //do somethings, without goroutines if key is not 2
    // strire in result var 
    return result 
}

func main() {
    ruleList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for _, val := range ruleList{
        go func(key int) {
            ruleCalled(key)
        }(val)
    }
  fmt.Println("done!")
}

Can someone please help me to find below question's answer
Best way to use goroutines in golang, especially in situations where one goroutine calls another?
How to avoid race condtion ?

Does this answer your question? How to wait for all goroutines to finish without using time.Sleep? (sync.WaitGroup is a common approach, using a channel is another option). Please try to ask one question (avoiding race conditions is really a different question look here).

Thanks a lot @Brits if a goroutine G1 call another goroutine G2 who will be responsible for handling G2, is it G1 or main process?

That depends on your requirements (in some cases you might want G1 to terminate before G2). Note this answer.

You can use helper libraries to work with goroutunes, such as pipers
import github.com/kozhurkin/pipers

func rule2() ([]int, error) {
    ruleList2 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    pp := pipers.FromArgs(ruleList2, func(i int, rule int) (int, error) {
        return rule * rule, nil
    })
    return pp.Resolve()
}

func main() {
    ruleList := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    pp := pipers.FromArgs(ruleList, func(i int, rule int) ([]int, error) {
        if rule == 2 {
            return rule2()
        }
        return []int{rule}, nil
    })

    res, err := pp.Resolve()

    fmt.Println(res, err)
    // [[1] [1 4 9 16 25] [3] [4] [5]] <nil>

}

If you don't need error handling, you can simplify it
import github.com/kozhurkin/pipers/pips

func rule2() []int {
    ruleList2 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    return pips.FromArgs(ruleList2, func(i int, rule int) int {
        return rule * rule
    })
}

func main() {
    ruleList := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    res := pips.FromArgs(ruleList, func(i int, rule int) []int {
        if i == 2 {
            return rule2()
        }
        return []int{rule}
    })

    fmt.Println(res)
    // [[1] [2] [1 4 9 16 25] [4] [5]]

}

